# Java missing text on zulu jdk

Tags: java

In our project we've switching to a zulu version of Java 8, however we encountered a bug, which appeares out strangely. We are rendering a menu using the following code:

```
        JButton button = category.getButton();
        button.setFont(categoryFont);
        button.setForeground(menuConfig.getMenuForeground());
        button.setText(choice.getLabel());
        button.setBackground(colors[colorIndex++ % colors.length]);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        button.setActionCommand(String.valueOf(i));
        panel.add(category);
        categoryButtons.add(category);
```

In debug mode, everything is on it's places, everything works no problem, but when we start it, there are rendered 6 buttons (as it meant to be), and 3 of them are having the text, but 3 of them are just with no text, empty buttons. On other JDK it works just fine, without issues, however on zulu:
8u202b05
Zulu: 8.36.0.1
the text is not present. After upgrade to the latest zulu the text appeared and everything is just fine , but it's not a compliant solution for us to upgrade, does somebody knows what can be the problem here?

Comment: Sounds like a vendor specific bug. Talk to azul - you may have to give them money.

Comment: It appears they fixed the bug after. So upgrade to 8u322b06.